# Ratio of sides in a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

The problem :

Let the lengths of bases $AD$ and $BC$ of trapezoid $ABCD$ be $a$ and $b$ ($a>b$). Find the length of segment $MN$ whose endpoints divide $AB$ and $CD$ in the ratio $AM:MB$ = $DN:NC$ = $p:q$.

I tried constructing a segment $BF$ ($F$ lies on $AD$, $BF || CD$), But can't go further.

How do I go about it?

Comment: Extend $AB$, $DC$ to form a triangle, then use similar triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue with your construction of BF || CD and observe that the triangles BAF and BME are similar (E: intersection of MN and BF), which establishes

$$\frac{MN- b}{a-b}= \frac q{p+q}$$
and yields

$$MN= \frac{aq +bp }{p+q}$$

Comment: I fail to see the similarity.

Comment: @AkshatVats - it is due to ME || AD

Comment: Ok now I get it. Thanks!